# Lazy loading class instance methods

Tags: python

The following lazy loading code seems to work.  Besides loss of introspection, is there any hidden danger in this way of lazy loading?

### myprog.py

```
from myclass import myclass
mc = myclass()
mc.nosuchfunc()
mc.otherfunc()
```

### myclass.py

```
class myclass(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        exec('import ' + name)
        exec('self.' + name + ' = ' + name + '.' + name)
        return eval('self.' + name)
```

### nosuchfunc.py

```
def nosuchfunc():
    print __name__
```

### otherfunc.py

```
def otherfunc():
    print __name__
```

### Update:

Extended Daniel's solution to support organizing class module files and their method module files in the same subdirectories:

```
class myclass(object):
    def unsupportedfunc(self, *args):
        print "unsupported method:", self._last__getattr__
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        self._last__getattr__ = name
        try:
            module = __import__(name, globals(), locals(), [], 1)
            func = getattr(module, name)
            setattr(self, name, func)
            return func
        except:
            return self.unsupportedfunc
```

Now I need to figure out how to distinguish an attempt to access a function type from attempt to access other attribute types.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't use `exec` or `eval`. It's not very clear, what happens:

```
class myclass(object):
    def __getattr__(self, name):
        module = __import__(name)
        func = getattr(module, name)
        setattr(self, name, func)
        return func
```

Comment: Wow.  That seems a lot cleaner.  I haven't tried it yet.  Will try it out and update.

Comment: Thanks Daniel.  This works.  Now to place the class module files with their method module files in the same directories.